# AutoMapper collections of strings to object properties in a collection of objects

Tags: c#, arrays, automapper, enumerable

I'm trying to map an object containing enumerable collections of strings into an object containing an enumerable collection objects whose properties contain the data in those collections.

Consider the following source class:

```cs
class Source
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Makes { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Models { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Variants { get; set; }
}
```

And the following destination classes:

```cs
class Destination
{
    public IEnumerable<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
}

class Vehicle
{
    public string Makes { get; set; }
    public string Models { get; set; }
    public string Variants { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to map `Source` into `Destination`, using the positional location of each `Source` collection value to map to the properties of a new `Vehicle`, and add that to the `Destination.Vehicles` collection. So, if the `Source` collections each contain 20 items, I would expect the `Destination.Vehicles` collection to contain 20 `Vehicle` items.

I've tried the following configuration, but it doesn't resolve out-of-the-box:

```cs
    CreateMap<Source, Destination>();
    CreateMap<Source, Vehicle>();
```

I then went on to try the advice given in [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13338523/1039402) to a question about flattening nested arrays, but soon became very complex.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't bother trying to leverage AutoMapper to piece things together. The mapping to the destination's `Vehicles` property should be a delegate (not an expression) that uses a couple `.Zip` calls on the source's properties. Write the `.Zip` calls first and get hat working, then put that into a mapping.

Comment: @madreflection, even better, since .NET 6 `Zip()` supports 3 enumerables. So this is just a single Zip call now.

Comment: Thanks @madreflection & @NPras. To be honest, I'd missed the ```.Zip()``` call... Every day's a school day... ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @madreflection in the comment, you can implement the [Custom converter](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-type-converters.html) with [`Enumerable.Zip()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-8.0#system-linq-enumerable-zip-3(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-1))-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-2)))) to merge those 3 arrays.

```cs
CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
    .ConvertUsing((src, dst) =>
    {
        dst = new Destination();
                    
        dst.Vehicles = src.Makes
            .Zip(src.Models, src.Variants)
            .Select(x => new Vehicle
            {
                Makes = x.Item1,
                Models = x.Item2,
                Variants = x.Item3
            })
            .ToList();
                    
            return dst;
});
```

If your .NET Version doesn't support the `Enumerable.Zip()` with three parameters, then you have to implement to merge the arrays as below:

```cs
int maxElement = new int[] { src.Makes.Count(), src.Models.Count(), src.Variants.Count() }
    .Max();
                    
var vehicles = new List<Vehicle>();
for (int i = 0; i < maxElement; i++)
{
    vehicles.Add(new Vehicle
        {
            Makes = src.Makes.ElementAtOrDefault(i),
            Models = src.Models.ElementAtOrDefault(i),
            Variants = src.Variants.ElementAtOrDefault(i)
        });
}
dst.Vehicles = vehicles;
```

Comment: [Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/d17wiC)

Comment: Thanks @Yong Shun... I your response is really helpful. While my example was a little contrived, the actual problem has multiple collections, not just three. This has really set me off on the right track though, so thank you once again.

Comment: Hi @Kaine, you are welcome. Ya, if you have multiple collections, you should consider the second approach, get the max number of those collections, iterate and get the value of collection by index.